# gcc: how to produce ELF where file size equals mem size for all LOAD segments without custom linker script?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, elf

I have to produce an ELF binary with gcc from a Hello World-program written in C, where the `mem size` equals the `file size` in all LOAD-segments of the ELF file. My experience says me, that I can prevent this if I move `.bss` into `.data` in a custom linker script. But in my case, I want to achieve this without a custom linker script.

Is there a way I can force all LOAD-segments to have the same file size as mem size with an option for GCC?

Background: I'm working on enabling Linux binaries on a custom OS. The ELF-Loader so far is pretty basic and testing/developing will be much simpler, if I just can map the ELF as it is (as long as all LOAD-segments are page-aligned)..

Comment: Did you try to use "objcopy" or other tools to change the segments before linking? -- Why don't you want to use an custom linker script? -- The additional effort to provide BSS memory is most probably quite small. Why don't you invest it? You need to provide a stack as well.

Comment: Adding a `memset` call to zero the `.bss` to your ELF loader is a far easier solution than trying to hack an existing linux ELF binary. Even with that, there will be bigger issues to deal with [requiring more features to be added to the ELF loader]. Why not just port linux's ELF loader to your platform? It's GPLv2 copyright/licensing. Is that an issue [and why]?

Comment: No, but I needed a pragmatic and quick solution for my master thesis project. I created a roottask for the microkernel https://github.com/cyberus-technology/hedron that only can load a roottask if its ELF file has MEMSIZE==FILESIZE for each LOAD segment. I added my solution from then down below.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, I provide the solution that includes a dedicated linker script. The relevant excerpt is the following:

```
    .data ALIGN(4K) :
    {
      *(.data .data.*)

      /* Putting .bss into the .data segment simplifies loading an ELF file especially in kernel
         scenarios. Some basic ELF loaders in OS dev space require MEMSIZE==FILESIZE for each
         LOAD segment. The zeroed memory will land "as is" in the ELF and increase its size.

         I'm not sure why but "*(COMMON)" must be specified as well so that the .bss section
         actually lands in .data. But the GNU ld doc also does it like this:
         https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Input-Section-Common.html */

      *(COMMON)
      *(.bss .bss.*)
    } : rw
```

It is important that the output section is not called ".bss" and that
the section contains more than just ".bss". Otherwise, the "FILESIZE != MEMSIZE" optimization is done where the ELF loader needs to provide zeroed memory.